# Is it possible to dump an Android partition with file-based encryption (FBE)?

Tags: encryption, storage

Consider an unrooted Android 9.0 device with [file-based encrypted (FBE)](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based), a [locked bootloader](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/locking_unlocking) and only recovery and download modes available. Is there any way to dump the internal storage either to the SD card or via USB, especially the user data partition `/data`?

Note: The objective is not to decrypt the data, but merely to gain *read access* to the bit patterns residing in `/data`.

Comment: You're only hope (without physically accessing the disk) would be through ADB and I don't think there are any commands that will do as you ask. But even if there is a command, FBE encrypts the file system with a Device Encryption (DE) key, meaning the data be *extra* useless unless you can physically extract the DE key from the device. Also, the DE key is per user too, so you can't even root the phone afterwards to perform cryptographic operations with the DE key (factory reset wipes the old DE key and creates a new user with a new DE key).

Comment: I should add that this is specific to Android 10+. Older versions that supported FBE had fewer protections (i.e. meta-data wasn't required to be encrypted prior to Android 10+).

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 *"FBE encrypts the file system with a Device Encryption (DE) key"* - What does this imply? Are you suggesting that on top of a file-by-file encryption there is an additional layer that encrypts the entire disk again (meaning an additional encryption of the already individually encrypted files)? Please clarify

Comment: DE and CE keys are loose terms. They just refer to keys that are derived from the device itself versus the user's credentials, respectively. The key that is used to encrypt the file system contents is derived from *both* a device generated key and the user's credentials. This means that decrypting data straight from disk needs more than just the password, it needs a DE key. And the phones that provide a StrongBox will require physical extraction of the keys from the StrongBox. For phone's like the Pixel 6, the StrongBox has built in tamper detection.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 This if off-topic

Comment: You asked me to clarify what I meant. I guess I didn't explicitly answer your question, so I will do that now: "Are you suggesting that on top of a file-by-file encryption there is an additional layer that encrypts the entire disk again" -- No, the file system contents is not encrypted twice (at least no in this aspect). Rather, the encryption key that is used is partly derived from a DE key. So, if you want to look at the raw data of the disk, then you're going to see garbage regardless of whether you have user credentials or not. If this hasn't been helpful, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: @free_coupons_for_sale_1023 No, that was actually helpful. The reason behind this question is not decryption of data (as stated explicitly), but targeting individual files for deletion (e.g. setting all bits to zero). In order to do this, I need the information of how files are distributed over the memory, i.e. where the bits that make up a file are located. This information would be inaccessible if the entire disk had an additional encryption layer. If, however, only individual files are encrypted, then their individual memory locations should be stored somewhere in clear text...

Comment: ...i.e. beginning of file, end of file, and maybe offsets if the file is fragmented. And this location map of files is what I need access to, so I can pick out a specific memory region that is occupied by a single file (and by that file only) and flip the bits so as to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** possible to dump the `userdata` partition. According to the [FBE docs](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based#handling-updates):

> The recovery partition is unable to access the DE-protected storage on the `userdata` partition.

Therefore, you won't be able to read the `userdata` partition without extracting the storage drive from the device. Furthermore, if you are running Android 11+, then the [filesystem metadata is encrypted](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/metadata) with a device encryption key. So if your goal is to determine the location of a file, you would also need to extract the DE key from the physical component that protects it, if applicable.

From as far as I can tell, unless you have a cyber forensics lab, there is not an easy way to even get *read* access to the partition.

EDIT:
Looking at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72720323/does-file-based-encryption-fbe-in-contrast-to-full-disk-encryption-fde-allow), it sounds like you soft-bricked your device. In which case, if your goal is to recover the device, you can't without root, as mentioned on this [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/accidentally-deleted-wrong-package-through-adb-when-trying-to-uninstall-bloatware.3945961/):

> It fails because it's a system app. With root it's possible to install it but not without.
> You need to do a factory reset from recovery to get all the apps in /system/app and /system/priv-app back.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137593/discussion-on-answer-by-free-coupons-for-sale-1023-is-it-possible-to-dump-an-and).

Comment: you can dump it with a bootloader exploit like kamakiri or direct access to the chip, see forensicswiki